# Iterating over all columns of dataframe to find list of strings

Tags: pandas, dataframe, array-broadcasting

Suppose I have the following `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1':['x1','x2','x3'],
    'col2':['y1','y2','y3'],
    'col3':['z1','z2','z3'],
    'col4':['a1','b2','c3']
})
```

and a list of elements:

```
l = ['x1','x2','y3']
```

I want to search elements of `l` in all the columns of my `df`, as it stands from my list `x1` and `x2` appear in `col1` and `y3` is in `col2`, so I did:

```
df.loc[df['col1'].apply(lambda x: True if any(i in x for i in l) else False)|
       df['col2'].apply(lambda x: True if any(i in x for i in l) else False)]
```

which gives me

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0   x1   y1   z1   a1
1   x2   y2   z2   b2
2   x3   y3   z3   c3
```

as desired but the above method needs me to make a `|` operator for each column. So I wonder how can I do this iteration over all columns efficiently without using `|` for every column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much, *much* more efficient way of doing this would be to use numpy broadcasting.

```
row_mask = (df.to_numpy() == l[:, None, None]).sum(axis=0).any(axis=1)
filtered = df[row_mask]
```

Output:

```
>>> filtered
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0   x1   y1   z1   a1
1   x2   y2   z2   b2
2   x3   y3   z3   c3
```